# At least one web or worker role is required but none could be found

Tags: azure, tfs, msbuild

I am trying to **Build a cloud service** using **MSBuild** using **TFS** and requesting a New Build using a saved Build Definition. The project is dependent on many other projects.

**MSBuild Arguments** I am passing are /t:Publish /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /p:TargetProfile=Cloud.Testing /p:IsExecutingPublishTarget=true

But I am getting following **error**

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.2\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets (2756): WAT001 : **At least one web or worker role is required but none could be found**

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

**Solved**: Oh our other specialist developer had checked in the wrong .ccproj file file to the source control with missing reference to web role project :-)